# Is there a sequence container with external allocation of elements (in the STL)?

Tags: c++

I would like to use a [sequence container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) type like [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) but with external allocation of the contained elements. This requirement is in order to gain more control over the allocation.

Such elements would probably have to use a class template which contains the necessary members for linking the (list) elements.

It can be implemented, but I wonder if there is already a proven in use solution? I am bound to C++17 or older.

By external allocation of the element I mean that the definition, allocation and initialization is done outside the control of the container type. That object is then manually added to the container.

Comment: What do you mean by *external allocation of the contained elements*?

Comment: That the definition, allocation and initialization is done outside the control of the container type. That object is then manually added to the container.

Comment: You can specify a custom `Allocator` for the container.

Comment: Sounds like a `vector<unique_ptr<your_type>>` might be what your looking for.

Comment: Allocation is pretty much what defines the "containment" that a "container" does. If you don't contain the object, then is it really a container anymore? You can for example use a pointer. A pointer can point to an object allocated externally by someone somewhere.

Comment: @eerorika yes, I am actually looking for s.th. that links together linkable objects and contains a pointer to the "first" object. Adding member functions to iterate over the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you want fine-grained control over the list elements, to the level how they are joined, `Boost.Intrusive` could be an option.

`Boost.Intrusive` provides an intrusive `slist` class: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html

Comment: Thank you! Something like the [Boost.Intrusive "containers"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html) is what I am looking for. If it would be part of the STL, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a forward list is :

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class forward_list;
```

this is so that you can specify whichever allocator you want to use, with

```
forward_list<int, MyAllocator> my_list;
```

It's not the most trivial part of C++, but you can then read up on writing a custom allocator.

Alternatively, as @NathanOliver suggest,

```
forward_list<shared_ptr<Type>> myList;
forward_list<unique_ptr<Type>> myList;
```

might fit your needs as allocation will happen outside.

Comment: Using a `std::forward_list` with `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` or custom allocator would still mean, that the container would allocate memory (make copies of the objects...?)? [@eerorika observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174083/is-there-a-sequence-container-with-external-allocation-of-elements-in-the-stl/62174380#comment109961731_62174083) correctly that I am actually looking for a *non-owning* list kind of type.

Comment: using a `forward_list` with shared pointers would have the forward_list allocate memory for the pointers (one pointer + minimal overhead) not for the objects themselves. And definitely not copies. Whatever you end up going with, your container will need to allocate some memory.